# samba не удалось подключить ресурс windows невозможно выделить память

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba

В папку 1cbase заходит без проблем. 
Попытка зайти из ubuntu 16.04.

> Не удалось получить доступ к местоположению.  Не удалось подключить
>   ресурс windows: невозможно выделить память.

Попытка зайти из Windows 7

> Сетевая ошибка. Windows не может получить доступ к \\Nas-r2\сканер
>   Разрешение на доступ к \\Nas-r2\сканер отсутствует. Обратитесь к
>   сетевому администратору для получения доступа.

Настройка на сервере ubuntu 16.04:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   netbios name = NAS-R2
   security = user
[hb1c-base]
path = /home/hb1c/1cbase
browseble = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
users = hb1c
create mask = 0750
directory mask = 0750

[Сканер]
path = /home/nas-scanner/scanner
browseble = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
users = nas-scanner
create mask = 0766
directory mask = 0766

:~$ sudo ls -l /home/hb1c
итого 4
drwxr-x--- 2 hb1c hb1c 4096 июн 26 12:55 1cbase
:~$ sudo ls -l /home/nas-scanner
итого 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 nas-scanner nas-scanner 4096 июн 26 13:37 scanner
```

Решил костыльным путём, создал нового пользователя и прописал новые пути, проблема кроется где-то в настройках прав доступа, но в чём конкретно причина пока не определил, потому вопрос открыт.

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Вы таки нашли нормальное решение этой проблемы?У меня такая же проблема с расшариванием внешнего диска.